# LINQ Select Statement. Anonymous Method Returns Exception

Tags: c#, linq, task, async-await

When using an anonymous method in a LINQ `Select` statement does the anonymous method have to return a value?

When I do the following I get no errors:

```
await Task.WhenAll(list.Select(a => doSomething(a)));
```

But when I do this I get an error that says `type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage`:

```
await Task.WhenAll(list.Select(a => {
    doSomething(a);
    Log("Log Something");
    UpdateUI();
}));
```

Why does the first work and the second doesn't?

Here is the `doSomething` method:

```
private async Task doSomething(string a)
{
     HttpClient client = new HttpClient;
     // Do stuff
     string source = await client.PostAsync(a, content);
     // Extract data from source and store in text file.
}
```

Comment: what is the return type of doSomething ?

Comment: Well what does `doSomething` return? Note that in your second case, I'd expect you to get a compile-time error as it's not returning anything...

Comment: Just added doSomething method

Comment: @JonSkeet It doesn't return nothing, that's why I used Task.

Comment: @JamesJeffery: Then you should make the lambda expression async

Comment: @JonSkeet care to link me to any decent guides on this stuff? I think I've just jumped in a little above my head here.

Comment: @JamesJeffery: Well it's not really clear what you expected to happen in this case. There are lots of async resources around - look for starting points on MSDN, for example. (I don't have time to find them right now.)

Answer (score 5):

> When using an anonymous method in a LINQ Select statement does the anonymous method have to return a value?

Yes.  The signature of the `Select` method is:

```
public IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
```

so the selector *must* return a value.

With your first code snippet the return statement is implicit.  `doSomething` returns a value, and that value is what each item is projected to.

When you use a statement lambda, instead of an expression lambda, there is no implicit return statement.  Since your second code block is not returning anything, it doesn't match what `Select` expects.

Now, as for your actual problem.  What you want to do is project each task into a task that does something, then writes to the log when it's done and updates the UI.  You can use an `async` lambda to do this.  In an `async` lambda when there are no `return` statement it will still be returning a `Task` (just without a `Result`) instead of `void`.  And that's exactly what you want to do, project each task into another task.

```
await Task.WhenAll(list.Select(async a => {
    await doSomething(a);
    Log("Log Something");
    UpdateUI();
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the function you pass to `Select()` has to return a value, because the purpose of `Select` is to change one set of values into another set of values. How about this:

Define this method:

```
private async Task DoSomethingLogAndUpdate(string a)
{
     await doSomething(a);
     Log("Log Something");
     UpdateUI();
}
```

Then do:

```
await Task.WhenAll(list.Select(a => DoSomethingLogAndUpdate(a)));
```

Or to do this without defining a separate method:

```
await Task.WhenAll(list.Select(async a => {
    await doSomething(a);
    Log("Log Something");
    UpdateUI();
}));
```

Comment: This will write to the log and update the UI when *starting* `doSomething`, not when it finishes.

Comment: This will work, but ideally `Select` statements shouldn't have side-effects like this.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is a simple expression, so the type of that expression is used as the return type of the lambda.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx):

> A lambda expression with an expression on the right side of the => operator is called an expression lambda. Expression lambdas are used extensively in the construction of Expression Trees (C# and Visual Basic). **An expression lambda returns the result of the expression**

(Emphasis mine)

However, what you have is a *statement* lambda, which means that in order to return a value, you must have a `return` statement in the lambda body.